# Python Read json file, parse and add to database

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server, database

I have a JSON folder which I need to read all files and check if its class is delete or write, write to database, or delete from database the previous recorded number.

My database has a column for each key inside **data**, plus a column for datetime tag and the name of the file.

The data comes in this format.

```
{
    "class": "savSend",
    "data": {
        "booking": "6881823",
        "driversLicense": "007687074",
        "container": "TGBU691384",
        "driversId": "1447397930",
        "excessA": "0",
        "excessB": "0",
        "excessC": "0",
        "excessD": "0",
        "excessE": "0",
        "locks": [
            {
                "lacre": "HLG0258978",
                "tipo": "Lock Alpha"
            },
            {
                "lacre": "13077",
                "tipo": "Lock Bravo"
            }
        ],
        "mission": "EXP CH",
        "foreignDrive": false,
        "nameDrive": "ANTONIO MARCOS DE CAMARGO",
        "numberSav": "20221235501",
        "weight": "18975",
        "truck": "FCY4J89",
        "dolly": "DPF2C94",
        "container": "3700",
        "type": "1 Bug"
    }
}
```

And here is what I have tried...

```
server = 'mainserver'
db = 'MainDataBase'
UID = 'userName'
PWD = 'password'


for filename in os.listdir(destination_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(os.path.join(destination_dir, filename)) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + '; UID = ' + UID + '; PWD = ' + PWD + 'Trusted_Connection=yes')

            with conn as conn:

                keys = ["booking", "driversLicense", "container", "driversId", "excessA", "excessB", "excessC", "excessD", "excessE", "locks", "mission", "foreignDrive", "nameDrive", "numberSav", "weight", "truck", "dolly", "container", "type"]
                for entry in data:

                    values = [entry.get(key, None) for key in keys]


                    cmd = """INSERT INTO tab VALUES(
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?
                            );"""
                    conn.execute(cmd, values)

                conn.commit()





    # Closing file
    f.close()
```

And here is the error I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [106], in <cell line: 7>()
     16 keys = ["booking", "deadlineDate", "deadlineTime", "Number", "Name", "quantity"]
     17 for entry in data:
     18 
     19     
     20     
---> 21     values = [entry.get(key, None) for key in keys]
     23     
     24     
     25     
     26     cmd = """INSERT INTO tab VALUES(
     27                 ?,
     28                 ?,
     29                 ?,
     30                 ?
     31             );"""

Input In [106], in <listcomp>(.0)
     16 keys = ["booking", "deadlineDate", "deadlineTime", "Number", "Name", "quantity"]
     17 for entry in data:
     18 
     19     
     20     
---> 21     values = [entry.get(key, None) for key in keys]
     23     
     24     
     25     
     26     cmd = """INSERT INTO tab VALUES(
     27                 ?,
     28                 ?,
     29                 ?,
     30                 ?
     31             );"""

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: I tried to write up an answer, but it's hard to tell what you need to do since the sample json you provided isn't actually valid, and it's difficult to guess what the missing pieces are. Just remember that `data = json.load(f)` returns a dictionary of _the entire json file_, so when you do `for entry in data`, you're just looping over the keys of the dictionary, which are strings. Try `for entry in data.values()` or `for key, entry in data.items()`, and use print statements to feel your way around the dictionaries until you get access to the "data" section.

Comment: I unintentionally removed the } !
That code was working fine, until I changed the json to have "class" and "data", now when I pass the entry.get(key, None) for key in keys] I get that error back, but before I could send all the data into my table...

Comment: Aside... `values = [entry.get(key, None) for key in keys]` should cause `values` to contain six values for the keys `booking`, `deadlineDate`, `deadlineTime`, `Number`, `Name` and `quantity`. The SQL statement, `INSERT INTO tab VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`, is only expecting four values. Also insert statements should explicitly declare the columns that they're targeting otherwise they could get broken by future DDL changes to the schema, e.g.: `INSERT INTO tab (booking, deadlineDate, deadlineTime, Number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`.

Comment: You are correct @AlwaysLearning, I will have to fix that too! Thank you so much! But I seem to be having a problem with parsing the data from the strings to the database. I dont really know what to do. I have tried printing the values but even when I get the columns, printing the values with data.values() or data.items() I dont know how to proceed from there.... You imagine anyway ?

Comment: As already mentioned your example data isn't correctly serialized JSON: 1) the file should be an array of JSON objects, so it needs to start with `[` and finish with `]` array wrappers; 2) each object should be delimited by commas, so `[ {...} , {...}, {...} ]` and 3) being the last in each `data` object the `"quantity": 3,` property should not have a trailing comma `,` character.

Comment: After fixing your JSON file(s), noting that your six keys are properties of a nested `data` object, you should be able to retrieve their values with `values = [entry.get("data").get(key, None) for key in keys]`.

Comment: hey @AlwaysLearning I have fixed all! But when I try to retrieve the values with ```values = [entry.get("data").get(key, None) for key in keys]``` I am unable to do so... 
If I loop in data like such `for entry in data:
    print(entry)` I get class and data but not the nested `data` object... And trying to retrieve the values keeps returning to me `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
`